# How do I create an exception to a group action in click

Tags: python, python-click

I have a case where I'd like to run a common function (`check_upgrade()`) for most of my click commands, but there are a few cases where I don't want to run it.  Rather than relying on developers to remember to add a decorator or function call to explicitly run this check, I'd prefer to instead run it by default and then have a decorator that one can add (e.g. `@bypass_upgrade_check`) for commands where `check_upgrade()` should not run.

I was hoping for something like:

```
class State(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bypass_upgrade_check = False

pass_state = click.make_pass_decorator(State, ensure=True)

def bypass_upgrade_check(func):
    @pass_state
    def wrapper(state, *args, **kwargs):
        state.bypass_upgrade_check = True
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper 

@click.group()
@pass_state
def common(state):
    if not state.bypass_upgrade_check:
        check_upgrade()

@common.command()
def cmd1():
    # check_upgrade() runs here
    pass

@bypass_upgrade_check
@common.command()
def cmd2():
    # don't run check_upgrade() here
    pass
```

But this doesn't work.  It doesn't actually ever call the `bypass_upgrade_check()` function.

Is there a way to decorate a command in such a way that I can modify the state before the group code runs?  Or another method altogether that accomplishes this?

Comment: Do you realize that the decorator `bypass_upgrade_check` will run only once, just after the interpreter processes the function definition of `cmd2`?  It will not produce any output that you can see at that point, nor will it call the original `cmd2`.  It's not clear what you are trying to do here.  You seem to want clicks to execute some particular function "by default" but don't want "developers" of future event handlers to forget to call that function.  But you don't tell us what your environment is or how those developers go about adding a handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep track of which commands bypass the upgrade check, I suggest that in the bypass marking decorator you store that state on the `click.Command` object.  Then if you pass the `click.Context` to your group, you can then look at the command object to see if it is marked to allow skipping upgrade like:

#### Code:

```
def bypass_upgrade_check(func):
    setattr(func, 'do_upgrade_check', False)

@click.group()
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx):
    sub_cmd = ctx.command.commands[ctx.invoked_subcommand]
    if getattr(sub_cmd, 'do_upgrade_check', True):
        check_upgrade()
```

#### Test Code:

```
import click

def check_upgrade():
    click.echo('Checking Upgrade!')

def bypass_upgrade_check(func):
    setattr(func, 'do_upgrade_check', False)

@click.group()
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx):
    sub_cmd = ctx.command.commands[ctx.invoked_subcommand]
    if getattr(sub_cmd, 'do_upgrade_check', True):
        check_upgrade()

@cli.command()
def cmd1():
    # check_upgrade() runs here
    click.echo('cmd1')

@bypass_upgrade_check
@cli.command()
def cmd2():
    # don't run check_upgrade() here
    click.echo('cmd2')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    commands = (
        'cmd1',
        'cmd2',
    )

    import sys, time

    time.sleep(1)
    print('Click Version: {}'.format(click.__version__))
    print('Python Version: {}'.format(sys.version))
    for cmd in commands:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print('-----------')
            print('> ' + cmd)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            cli(cmd.split())

        except BaseException as exc:
            if str(exc) != '0' and \
                    not isinstance(exc, (click.ClickException, SystemExit)):
                raise
```

#### Results:

```
Click Version: 6.7
Python Version: 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
-----------
> cmd1
Checking Upgrade!
cmd1
-----------
> cmd2
cmd2
```

Comment: This works perfectly!  I had no idea that you could pull in the invoked_subcommand.  So simple and elegant, just what I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: This answer works great for top-level commands, but it doesn't work for subcommands.  Say I have sub-commands 'cmd1 sub1' and 'cmd1 sub2' and I want to disable the check for sub1 but not for sub2?  I tried adding the getattr check to the group definition for the subcommand, but that doesn't work because the top-level group will catch it first and since the 'cmd1' doesn't have an @bypass_upgrade_check, then it runs the upgrade check.  I think there needs to be a way to search through subcommands from the top-level.  Or perhaps there's another way to do this?

Comment: New question posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50282200/click-ow-do-i-apply-an-action-to-all-commands-and-subcommands-but-allow-a-comma