# Click: how do I apply an action to all commands and subcommands but allow a command to opt-out?

Tags: python, python-click

I have a case where I'd like to automatically run a common function, `check_upgrade()`, for most of my click commands and sub-commands, but there are a few cases where I don't want to run it. I was thinking I could have a decorator that one can add (e.g. `@bypass_upgrade_check`) for commands where `check_upgrade()` should not run.

I was hoping for something like (thanks [Stephen Rauch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50273080/7311767) for the initial idea):

```
def do_upgrade():
    print "Performing upgrade"

def bypass_upgrade_check(func):
    setattr(func, "do_upgrade_check", False)
    return func

@click.group()
@click.pass_context
def common(ctx):
    sub_cmd = ctx.command.commands[ctx.invoked_subcommand]
    if getattr(sub_cmd, "do_upgrade_check", True):
        do_upgrade()

@bypass_upgrade_check
@common.command()
def top_cmd1():
    # don't run do_upgrade() on top level command
    pass

@common.command()
def top_cmd2():
    # DO run do_upgrade() on top level command
    pass

@common.group()
def sub_cmd_group():
    pass

@bypass_upgrade_check
@sub_cmd.command()
def sub_cmd1():
    # don't run do_upgrade() on second-level command
    pass

@sub.command()
def sub_cmd2():
    # DO run do_upgrade() on second-level command
    pass
```

Unfortunately, this only works for the top-level commands, since `ctx.invoked_subcommand` refers to `sub_cmd_group` and not `sub_cmd1` or `sub_cmd2`.

Is there a way to recursively search through sub-commands, or perhaps using a custom Group to be able to achieve this functionality with both top-level commands as well as subcommands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to solve this is to build a custom decorator that pairs with a custom `click.Group` class:

#### Custom Decorator Builder:

```
def make_exclude_hook_group(callback):
    """ for any command that is not decorated, call the callback """

    hook_attr_name = 'hook_' + callback.__name__

    class HookGroup(click.Group):
        """ group to hook context invoke to see if the callback is needed"""

        def invoke(self, ctx):
            """ group invoke which hooks context invoke """
            invoke = ctx.invoke

            def ctx_invoke(*args, **kwargs):
                """ monkey patched context invoke """
                sub_cmd = ctx.command.commands[ctx.invoked_subcommand]
                if not isinstance(sub_cmd, click.Group) and \
                        getattr(sub_cmd, hook_attr_name, True):
                    # invoke the callback
                    callback()
                return invoke(*args, **kwargs)

            ctx.invoke = ctx_invoke

            return super(HookGroup, self).invoke(ctx)

        def group(self, *args, **kwargs):
            """ new group decorator to make sure sub groups are also hooked """
            if 'cls' not in kwargs:
                kwargs['cls'] = type(self)
            return super(HookGroup, self).group(*args, **kwargs)

    def decorator(func=None):
        if func is None:
            # if called other than as decorator, return group class
            return HookGroup

        setattr(func, hook_attr_name, False)

    return decorator
```

#### Using the decorator builder:

To use the decorator we first need to build the decorator like:

```
bypass_upgrade_check = make_exclude_hook_group(do_upgrade)
```

Then we need to use it as a custom class to `click.group()` like:

```
@click.group(cls=bypass_upgrade_check())
...
```

And finally, we can decorate any commands or sub-commands to the group that need to not use the callback like:

```
@bypass_upgrade_check
@my_group.command()
def my_click_command_without_upgrade():
     ...
```

#### How does this work?

This works because click is a well designed OO framework. The `@click.group()` decorator usually instantiates a `click.Group` object but allows this behavior to be over-ridden with the `cls` parameter. So it is a relatively easy matter to inherit from `click.Group` in our own class and over ride the desired methods.

In this case, we build a decorator that sets an attribute on any click function that does not need the callback called.  Then in our custom group, we monkey patch `click.Context.invoke()` of our context and if the command that is about to be executed has not been decorated, we call the callback.

#### Test Code:

```
import click

def do_upgrade():
    print("Performing upgrade")

bypass_upgrade_check = make_exclude_hook_group(do_upgrade)

@click.group(cls=bypass_upgrade_check())
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx):
    pass

@bypass_upgrade_check
@cli.command()
def top_cmd1():
    click.echo('cmd1')

@cli.command()
def top_cmd2():
    click.echo('cmd2')

@cli.group()
def sub_cmd_group():
    click.echo('sub_cmd_group')

@bypass_upgrade_check
@sub_cmd_group.command()
def sub_cmd1():
    click.echo('sub_cmd1')

@sub_cmd_group.command()
def sub_cmd2():
    click.echo('sub_cmd2')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    commands = (
        'top_cmd1',
        'top_cmd2',
        'sub_cmd_group sub_cmd1',
        'sub_cmd_group sub_cmd2',
        '--help',
    )

    import sys, time

    time.sleep(1)
    print('Click Version: {}'.format(click.__version__))
    print('Python Version: {}'.format(sys.version))
    for cmd in commands:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print('-----------')
            print('> ' + cmd)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            cli(cmd.split())

        except BaseException as exc:
            if str(exc) != '0' and \
                    not isinstance(exc, (click.ClickException, SystemExit)):
                raise
```

#### Results:

```
Click Version: 6.7
Python Version: 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
-----------
> top_cmd1
cmd1
-----------
> top_cmd2
Performing upgrade
cmd2
-----------
> sub_cmd_group sub_cmd1
sub_cmd_group
sub_cmd1
-----------
> sub_cmd_group sub_cmd2
Performing upgrade
sub_cmd_group
sub_cmd2
-----------
> --help
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  sub_cmd_group
  top_cmd1
  top_cmd2
```

Comment: Works great! It's definitely more complicated than the example that doesn't work with subcommands, but the flexibility is worth it in this case.

Comment: @agelter, it may seem complicated, but it really isn't in the context of this library.  What this is, is a window onto the underlying complexity of the click library. The brilliance of the library is that for the cases it it is designed for, it looks from the outside, to be quite simple. Well it isn't simple, it just looks that way, because the API is well designed. But even for the things it wasn't designed for, if you understand the base library, you can often, with a relatively small amount of code, make it do what you want.  Cheers, and glad this was useful.