# Click: how do I apply an action to all commands and subcommands but allow a command to opt-out (part duex)?

Tags: python, python-click

Building on [my initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50282200/7311767), I'd like to be able to have the body of a parent group run before I run my callback.

> I have a case where I'd like to automatically run a common function, check_upgrade(), for most of my click commands and sub-commands, but there are a few cases where I don't want to run it. I was thinking I could have a decorator that one can add (e.g. @bypass_upgrade_check) for commands where check_upgrade() should not run.

For example:

```
def do_upgrade():
    print("Performing upgrade")

bypass_upgrade_check = make_exclude_hook_group(do_upgrade)

@click.group(cls=bypass_upgrade_check())
@click.option('--arg1', default=DFLT_ARG1)
@click.option('--arg2', default=DFLT_ARG2)
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx, arg1, arg2):
    config.call_me_before_upgrade_check(arg1, arg2)

@bypass_upgrade_check
@cli.command()
def top_cmd1():
    click.echo('cmd1')

@cli.command()
def top_cmd2():
    click.echo('cmd2')

@cli.group()
def sub_cmd_group():
    click.echo('sub_cmd_group')

@bypass_upgrade_check
@sub_cmd_group.command()
def sub_cmd1():
    click.echo('sub_cmd1')

@sub_cmd_group.command()
def sub_cmd2():
    click.echo('sub_cmd2')
```

I'd like things to function like explained in [the initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50282200/7311767), but instead of executing `do_upgrade()` before executing the body of `cli()`, I'd like it to call:

```
cli() --> do_upgrade() --> top_cmd1()
```

for example.  Or for a nested command:

```
cli() --> sub_cmd_group() --> do_upgrade() --> sub_cmd1()
```

So I guess another way to phrase the question is:  is it possible to have the functionality from the original question, but have the callback be called right before the subcommand itself runs instead of being called before any of the Group blocks run?

The reason I need this is because the arguments passed in to the top-level CLI command indicate the server address to check for an upgrade.  I need this information to process `do_upgrade()`.  I can't pass this information directly to `do_upgrade()` because this server information is also used elsewhere in the application.  I can query it from `do_upgrade()` with something like `config.get_server()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a similar fashion to the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50284146/7311767), one way to solve this is to build a custom decorator that pairs with a custom `click.Group` class.  The added complication is to hook the `Command.invoke()` instead of the `Group.invoke()` so that the callback will be invoked immediately preceding the `Command.invoke()` and thus will be invoked after any `Group.invoke()`:

#### Custom Decorator Builder:

```
import click

def make_exclude_hook_command(callback):
    """ for any command that is not decorated, call the callback """

    hook_attr_name = 'hook_' + callback.__name__

    class HookGroup(click.Group):
        """ group to hook context invoke to see if the callback is needed"""

        def group(self, *args, **kwargs):
            """ new group decorator to make sure sub groups are also hooked """
            if 'cls' not in kwargs:
                kwargs['cls'] = type(self)
            return super(HookGroup, self).group(*args, **kwargs)

        def command(self, *args, **kwargs):
            """ new command decorator to monkey patch command invoke """

            cmd = super(HookGroup, self).command(*args, **kwargs)

            def hook_command_decorate(f):
                # decorate the command
                ret = cmd(f)

                # grab the original command invoke
                orig_invoke = ret.invoke

                def invoke(ctx):
                    """call the call back right before command invoke"""
                    parent = ctx.parent
                    sub_cmd = parent and parent.command.commands[
                        parent.invoked_subcommand]
                    if not sub_cmd or \
                            not isinstance(sub_cmd, click.Group) and \
                            getattr(sub_cmd, hook_attr_name, True):
                        # invoke the callback
                        callback()
                    return orig_invoke(ctx)

                # hook our command invoke to command and return cmd
                ret.invoke = invoke
                return ret

            # return hooked command decorator
            return hook_command_decorate

    def decorator(func=None):
        if func is None:
            # if called other than as decorator, return group class
            return HookGroup

        setattr(func, hook_attr_name, False)

    return decorator
```

#### Using the decorator builder:

To use the decorator we first need to build the decorator like:

```
bypass_upgrade = make_exclude_hook_command(do_upgrade)
```

Then we need to use it as a custom class to `click.group()` like:

```
@click.group(cls=bypass_upgrade())
...
```

And finally, we can decorate any commands or sub-commands to the group that need to not use the callback like:

```
@bypass_upgrade
@my_group.command()
def my_click_command_without_upgrade():
     ...
```

#### How does this work?

This works because click is a well designed OO framework. The `@click.group()` decorator usually instantiates a `click.Group` object but allows this behavior to be over-ridden with the `cls` parameter. So it is a relatively easy matter to inherit from `click.Group` in our own class and over ride the desired methods.

In this case, we build a decorator that sets an attribute on any click function that does not need the callback called.  Then in our custom group, we overide both the `group()` and the `command()` decorators so that we can we monkey patch `invoke()` on the command and if the command that is about to be executed has not been decorated, we call the callback.

#### Test Code:

```
def do_upgrade():
    click.echo("Performing upgrade")

bypass_upgrade = make_exclude_hook_command(do_upgrade)

@click.group(cls=bypass_upgrade())
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx):
    click.echo('cli')

@bypass_upgrade
@cli.command()
def top_cmd1():
    click.echo('cmd1')

@cli.command()
def top_cmd2():
    click.echo('cmd2')

@cli.group()
def sub_cmd_group():
    click.echo('sub_cmd_group')

@bypass_upgrade
@sub_cmd_group.command()
def sub_cmd1():
    click.echo('sub_cmd1')

@sub_cmd_group.command()
def sub_cmd2():
    click.echo('sub_cmd2')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    commands = (
        'top_cmd1',
        'top_cmd2',
        'sub_cmd_group sub_cmd1',
        'sub_cmd_group sub_cmd2',
        '--help',
    )

    import sys, time

    time.sleep(1)
    print('Click Version: {}'.format(click.__version__))
    print('Python Version: {}'.format(sys.version))
    for cmd in commands:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print('-----------')
            print('> ' + cmd)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            cli(cmd.split())

        except BaseException as exc:
            if str(exc) != '0' and \
                    not isinstance(exc, (click.ClickException, SystemExit)):
                raise
```

#### Results:

```
Click Version: 6.7
Python Version: 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
-----------
> sub_cmd_group sub_cmd2
cli
sub_cmd_group
Performing upgrade
sub_cmd2
-----------
> top_cmd1
cli
cmd1
-----------
> top_cmd2
cli
Performing upgrade
cmd2
-----------
> sub_cmd_group sub_cmd1
cli
sub_cmd_group
sub_cmd1
-----------
> sub_cmd_group sub_cmd2
cli
sub_cmd_group
Performing upgrade
sub_cmd2
-----------
> --help
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --arg1 TEXT
  --arg2 TEXT
  --help       Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  sub_cmd_group
  top_cmd1
  top_cmd2
```